# Which Realtek audio codec is the most powerful and advanced?

Tags: motherboard, audio

I am an audiophile. I have very expensive and advanced audio devices. I have Sennheiser HD 800 S, HyperX ProCast, Edifier AirPulse A200. I am concerned with buying a motherboard with the best audio codec for my devices. I don't care about price at all, I care only about specs. Which Realtek audio codec is the most powerful and advanced?

Comment: If you want quality you should be looking at external DACs, not internal. As the ProCast needs a 'real' mic preamp, why not use that?

Comment: I believe internal will be enough for me.

Comment: You want to drive 1200 buck headphones off a 50 cent DAC… your call, I guess...

Comment: 50 cents? I didn't understand this joke.

Comment: It's not a joke, that's about what the chipset would cost.

Comment: Realtek codecs are better than 50 cent DAC.